# flutter music current index not updating

Tags: flutter, audio-player

```
     List<SongModel> songs = item.data!;

return ListTile(
                      onTap: () {
                        audioPlayer.setAudioSource(
                          createPlayList(songs),
                          initialIndex: index,
                        );
                        audioPlayer.play();
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => PlayerView(
                              audioPlayer: audioPlayer,
                              songsList: songs,
                              initialIndex: index,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
    
    
    ConcatenatingAudioSource createPlayList(List<SongModel> songs) {
        List<AudioSource> sources = [];
        for (var song in songs) {
          sources.add(AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(song.uri!)));
        }
        return ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: sources);
      }
```

I am using this method to get all the songs from audio query and it's working fine if i want to play a single song on the player view which is :

```
class PlayerView extends StatefulWidget {
  PlayerView({
    Key? key,
    required this.audioPlayer,
    required this.songsList,
    required this.initialIndex,
  }) : super(key: key);

  AudioPlayer audioPlayer;
  List<SongModel> songsList;
  int initialIndex;

  @override
  State<PlayerView> createState() => _PlayerViewState();
}

class _PlayerViewState extends State<PlayerView> {
  bool isPlaying = false;
  String currentSongTitle = '';
  int currentIndex = 0;

  Stream<DurationState> get durationState =>
      Rx.combineLatest2<Duration, Duration?, DurationState>(
        widget.audioPlayer.positionStream,
        widget.audioPlayer.durationStream,
        (position, duration) =>
            DurationState(position: position, total: duration ?? Duration.zero),
      );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.audioPlayer.currentIndexStream.listen((index) {
      if (index != null) {
        _updateCurrentPlayingSongDetails(index);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
```

i am updating title and artquery in this way

```
 widget.songsList[widget.initialIndex].title,
QueryArtworkWidget(
                id: widget.songsList[widget.initialIndex].id,
```

and this method for skipping to next or previous song which is working fine means it's skipping to next or previous but only one like if i am playing song 1 and i skip to next means song2 and then try to skip again it will keep playing song 2 which as far as i think is due to not updating the song list and i tried to do it but it's not working as it's supposed to be.

```
void _updateCurrentPlayingSongDetails(int index) {
    setState(() {
      if (widget.songsList.isNotEmpty) {
        currentSongTitle = widget.songsList[index].title;
        currentIndex = index;
      }
    });
  }
```

So the conclusion of the problem is :
Main page view which is the first one is sending single index to other screen due to which only first played song can be skipped and it's also not updating the current state.
Hope i will find a solution from any of you and i will be waiting cuz i am trying to fix it from days but i am new in flutter so you can expect this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use currentIndexStream, eg:

```
final AudioPlayer player = GetIt.I.get<AudioPlayer>();
player.currentIndexStream.listen((index) {
  if (index != null) {
    // your code
  }
});
```